# Cordova build: Command failed with exit code 8

Tags: android, cordova, maven

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+.     Required by:         :android:unspecified
>   Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
>   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https:.,.,.//repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   Connection to https:...,//repo1.maven.org refused

This is my error message.

It seems that it is not accessible to the central warehouse, but I have set up proxy for gradle, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already resolved my problem.
find your .gradle folder，Open the gradle.properties file，and write down

```
#systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
#systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
#systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
#systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
#systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
#
#systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
#systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
#systemProp.https.proxyUser=userid
#systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
#systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

Because it's the beginning of https，you must set it，not only http